# Creating custom text expansion for password template

Tags: shortcut-keys, password, scripts

Let me explain.
As a security measure, my current password system is a complicated combination of letters and symbols, to ensure a different password is used for each website I use a base password as a template and insert 2 key letters that represent the site that the password is for.

e.g:

base password: t$6{}dValzg2{}Scmsk

the brackets represent where the key letters that change would be

for example, for facebook: t$6**f**dValzg2**b**Scmsk

I think you get the idea.

I want to create some kind of text expansion program / script for ubuntu that would allow me to type in 2 letters for example fb, press some shortcut keys and expand the text into the full password.

I'm fairly new to Linux (under a week) and I have some programming knowledge, what I need is a push in the right direction with some guidance and an outline of what I need in order to accomplish this.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `bash` script to the job :

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
if [[ ${#1} = 2 ]]; then
    first="${1:0:1}"
    second="${1:1:1}"
    echo "t\$6${first}dValzg2${second}Scmsk"
else
    echo 'Then length of input string must be two'   
fi
```

`first` and `second` are variables containing the first and second character respectively of the given input string which are generated by using the `bash` parameter expansion pattern `${parameter:offset:length}`.

Save the script as e.g. `pass_gen.sh`, make it executable (`chmod u+x pass_gen.sh`) and run it as :

```
/path/to/pass_gen.sh fb
```

or while in the same directory where the script is :

```
./pass_gen.sh fb
```

Pass the input string as first argument.

Example :

```
$ ./pass_gen.sh fb
t$6fdValzg2bScmsk

$ ./pass_gen.sh tw
t$6tdValzg2wScmsk

$ ./pass_gen.sh fbc
Then length of input string must be two
```

Comment: Wont this only work in the terminal? is there a way to make this universal?I mainly need this online. thanks very much btw

Comment: your question clearly mentioned script..could you please clarify what is your final goal and how are you planning to achieve that ?